# Read only postgres user

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a user that only have read privileges on tables. The trick is alter default_transaction_read_only parameter:

```
create user 'readonly' password 'anypass';
alter user readonly set default_transaction_read_only = on;
```

Next, there are n schemes in my databases, How can I give give permission to all tables in every scheme?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That won't help, the user can change the the setting `default_transaction_read_only` without any problems.The only safe way to do this is to revoke all update privileges from the user.

Comment: Another question that might help: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35316/why-is-a-new-user-allowed-to-create-a-table